# Emacs 24.5 with prelude stuck on contacting host melpa.org

Tags: emacs, emacs24, melpa, emacs-prelude

I'm running emacs 24.5 installed via homebrew.
for some weird reason my emacs gets stuck on Contacting host: melpa.org:80

I even tried a fresh install of emacs (removed .emacs.d folder as well)
Also i'm able to ping the url melpa.org through terminal.

Any ideas on how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try switching to HTTPS?  I have

```
(setq package-archives '(("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
                         ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))

;; from https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2015/11/editor-malware.html
;; needs "brew install gnutls" and "pip install certifi", perhaps with sudo
(let ((trustfile
       (replace-regexp-in-string
        "\\\\" "/"
        (replace-regexp-in-string
         "\n" ""
         (shell-command-to-string "python -m certifi")))))
  (setq tls-program
        (list
         (format "/usr/local/bin/gnutls-cli --insecure --x509cafile %s -p %%p %%h"
                 trustfile)))
  (setq gnutls-verify-error t))
```